# Using dummy expression to force db2 Query Optimization

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization, sqlperformance

Is there any way to force DB2 optimization(Query optimization) Using the expression like   (0<>0).
I can see this expression in embedded SQL statements in PL1 program.

(FIELD = 'VALUE' OR 0 <> 0)

DBA suggests that this expression force DB2 optimizer and removing the expression will be useful to use Indexes.  Is there any documentation regarding this. I don't see documentation of using an expression to specify db2 optimizer/Query Optimization usage.

DB2 server platform: Linux DB2 version:  11.5.7.0

Comment: Is your Db2-server running on Z/OS ?  It matters , because some platforms support hints , either appended to the SQL code or external to the code. You should always specify your Db2-server __platform and version__ when asking for help with Db2.

Comment: It is in linux.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend not to use such additional predicates.
Nobody will know when and why these had been added anf if they are still valid or meanwhile contra productive.

There are "official" ways to make the optimizer move to better decisions and a more performant access path.
I suggest you have a look at following topics (in this order):

- current statistics
- Indexes
- statistical views
- optimization guidelines

Comment: In this specific case, it was used for  Dynamic SQL to force DB2optimizer(according to DBA).  According to DBA when this expression is being used it is not using table indexes.

Comment: This expression was being used previously, then the Query became slower, Then DBA advised to remove it to make use of indexes(how?). After removing the expression, it became faster.